# Echo the selected items in drop down menus

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I created two dropdown menu populated by two different database tables. I also created a button to press after having chosen something from the menu. What I would like to do (but I am not able to) is to print on the screen the selected items. Below the code I wrote until now:

```
<?php
require_once('assets/index.php');
    $result1 = $conn->query("select * from partenze");
    $result2 = $conn->query("select * from arrivi");
    echo "<html>";echo "<body>";echo "<form action='index.php'>"; echo "Select your Departure: <select name='p_id'>";
    while ($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
                  unset($pid, $pname);
                  $pid = $row1['p_id'];
                  $plocalita = $row1['p_localita']; 
                  echo '<option value="'.$pid.'">'.$plocalita.'</option>';}
    echo "</select><br>";echo "Select your Arrival: <select name='a_id'>";
    while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
                  unset($aid, $aname);
                  $aid = $row2['a_id'];
                  $alocalita = $row2['a_localita']; 
                  echo '<option value="'.$aid.'">'.$alocalita.'</option>';}
    echo "</select>";

    echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Get Selected Values' />"; echo "</form>";

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $selected_val1 = $_POST['p_id'];  // Storing Selected Value In Variable
    $selected_val2 = $_POST['a_id'];  // Storing Selected Value In Variable
    echo "You have selected :" .$selected_val1. " and " .$selected_val2;  // Displaying Selected Value
    }

echo "</body>";echo "</html>";
?>
```

Comment: This will not work Please don't do this make one simple variable and push value with the same variable and print out side of the loop like
$option .=$option;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print the value that is selected in dropdown list in PHP or set it as selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34516869/how-to-print-the-value-that-is-selected-in-dropdown-list-in-php-or-set-it-as-sel)

Comment: Basically you can't do this with pure `PHP` you need to combine `JavaScript1 with this.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to retrieve data by `$_POST` data. but in form you haven't specify request method. So it will take `get` method by default. So you need to specify `method=post` in form to get request from POST

```
<?php
require_once('assets/index.php');
    $result1 = $conn->query("select * from partenze");
    $result2 = $conn->query("select * from arrivi");
    echo "<html>";
    echo "<body>";
    echo "<form action='index.php' method='post'>"; 
    echo "Select your Departure: 
    <select name='p_id'>";
    while ($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
                  unset($pid, $pname);
                  $pid = $row1['p_id'];
                  $plocalita = $row1['p_localita']; 
                  echo '<option value="'.$pid.'">'.$plocalita.'</option>';}
    echo "</select><br>";echo "Select your Arrival: <select name='a_id'>";
    while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
                  unset($aid, $aname);
                  $aid = $row2['a_id'];
                  $alocalita = $row2['a_localita']; 
                  echo '<option value="'.$aid.'">'.$alocalita.'</option>';}
    echo "</select>";

    echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Get Selected Values' />"; 
    echo "</form>";

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $selected_val1 = $_POST['p_id'];  // Storing Selected Value In Variable
    $selected_val2 = $_POST['a_id'];  // Storing Selected Value In Variable
    echo "You have selected :" .$selected_val1. " and " .$selected_val2;  // Displaying Selected Value
    }

echo "</body>";echo "</html>";
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Desai. Actually in this way, after I press the button, it appears "You have selected :" but no information about my 2 variables. Do you know what is the mistake in my code? @B.Desai

Comment: according to code it looks perfect make sure while you assigning `$pid` and `$aid` to select-option value its not blank